# How to download one zip file which contains more zip files in asp.net C# 2.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I want to download the parent Zip file which contains more zip files in asp.net c#.

Following code work for single zip file which have more .pdf,.txt ect.. files.

```
zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
zip.AddEntry(filename, "");
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "filename.zip");
zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?  Do you get an exception?  The contents of the zip file shouldn't matter.

Comment: How big is the parent zip file? IIS has a default size limit for responses, but you can increase that with a setting in the web.config.